# if my umask is 0002 then why does `mkdir dirname` create directories with drwxrwxr-x permission?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, ubuntu-18.04, umask

If my umask is 0002 then why does `mkdir dirname` create a directory with `drwxrwxr-x` permission? I should think that it would create it with `d-------w-` permission.

Comment: [What is `umask` and how does it work?](https://askubuntu.com/q/44542/693277)

Comment: UMask is inverted. 002 umask is equivalent to 775 permissions